# How to addClass to the next td on link hover in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, html-table

I have 6 tds like this:

```
<td><a href="#">link</a></td>
<td>Some text here</td>

<td><a href="#">link</a></td>
<td>Some other text here</td>

<td><a href="#">link</a></td>
<td>Some other other text here</td>
```

And I would like to addClass after hover over a link to the next td. E.g. If I hover over the a link from the second td the next td will have a class for  instance **active** like this

```
<td><a href="#">link</a></td>
<td>Some text here</td>

<td><a href="#">link</a></td> <!-- hoovering over this link -->
<td class="active">Some other text here</td> <!-- and this td will have class active-->

<td><a href="#">link</a></td>
<td>Some other other text here</td>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().addClass('someclass');
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().next().removeClass('someclass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("a").hover(function(){
       $(this).parent().next("td").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtJ9B/)

Answer (score 1):

This will not only add class on hover but also remove it when you hover out of a link. It also works when you have other  tags on your page. Not only those inside td.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td > a").hover(function() {
       $(this).parent().next("td").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```